# Symfony 3 select multiple users

Tags: php, symfony, web

So I'm creating a web site like 'todo' list(something like todoist, trello). Now I'm trying to make that any user could assign tasks for other users. I've already made that any user could assign task for any other USER. But I would like to make that any user could assign the same task for as many users as he wish. And I'm a little bit stuck here. Not sure how to make that the user could select as many users as he wish.

Here is an example of my web page: [image]

F.e. I would like to asign a task for users "admin" and "jonukas" in one form. Is it possible?

**Any help is appreciated.**

**---I'm not asking to write a code for me I just need some advises or examples---**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need two things:

1. ManyToMany relationship between `User` and `Task` entities in order to be possible to persist your multi selection.
2. Configure your form field to accept multiple options being selected. I guess you're using `EntityType`, so all you need is to set `multiple` option to `true`.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#multiple